# jQuery conditional statement that will check the value of all buttons with the same class

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I currently have a small page with 9 buttons on it. Four are assigned one class, and five are assigned another. Throughout the life of the page, the values of the 5 could change to one of two values. I would like to make an if in jQuery statement that checks the values of the five buttons that are of the same class. When their values all equal one thing, a function is fired.

I have the function working, I'm just having trouble creating a conditional statement.

Edit: I can't really give all of the code. It would take up the whole page. Here are the buttons I want to monitor:

```
<input id="link1" type="button" value="[+] Expand" onclick="toggleVisibility('table1', 'link1')" class="expander" />
<input id="link2" type="button" value="[+] Expand" onclick="toggleVisibility('table2', 'link2')" class="expander" />
<input id="link3" type="button" value="[+] Expand" onclick="toggleVisibility('table3', 'link3')" class="expander" />
<input id="link4" type="button" value="[+] Expand" onclick="toggleVisibility('table4', 'link4')" class="expander" />
<input id="link5" type="button" value="[+] Expand" onclick="toggleVisibility('table5', 'link5')" class="expander" />
```

Here is the jQuery function I want to fire when all of the values of these five buttons are "[+] Expand"

```
function () { $("#bottom-wrap").addClass("absolute-bottom") }
```

Comment: Please provide your basic button scenario in a jsFiddle - it's hard to understand what you mean from your description.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only five buttons with the same class, and you wish to check if all five have the same value, you could always do:

```
var elem = $(".expander"); 

elem.on('change', function() {
    if ( elem.filter("[value='[+] Expand']").length == elem.length)
        $("#bottom-wrap").addClass("absolute-bottom");
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yB6vM/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of the elements every time one of them updates. The following function should give you what you want:

```
function buttonClassMatches(){
var firstClass;
var sameClass = true;
$('input[type="button"]').each(function(){
if(firstClass == null){firstClass = $(this).attr("class");}
if(firstClass != $(this).attr("class")){sameClass = false;}
});
if(sameClass){doYourFunction();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt--it may need slight modifications.  If you provide a jsFiddle or something, I can make sure it works properly.

```
$(".fiveClass").change(function(){ //Add an event handler to jQuery's change event
   var allSame = true;
   var first;
   $(".fiveClass").each(function(){ //Check each element with the class "fiveClass"
      if( typeof first == "undefined" ){
          first = $(this).val();//could also try .text() depending on type of DOM node
      }
      allSame = allSame && (first === $(this).text());
   }
   if( allSame ){
      //do something.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var first,
    same = true;

$('.class').each(function(index, element) {
    if (index == 0) first = $(this).val();
    else {
        if (first != $(this).val()) {
            same = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
});

if (same) func();
```